# how to filter a .csv/.txt file using a list from another .txt

Tags: python, excel

So I have an excel sheet that contains in this order:

Sample_name | column data | column data2 | column data ... n

I also have a .txt file that contains

Sample_name

What I want to do is filter the excel file for only the sample names contained in the .txt file.  My current idea is to go through each column (excel sheet) and see if it matches any name in the .txt file, if it does, then grab the whole column. However, this seems like a nonefficient way to do it. I also need to do this using python.  I was hoping someone could give me an idea on how to approach this better.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - your basic approach gives you a starting point. You should write some actual code, pick a Python package to read the Excel data with (there's many options, and they are easy to find) and if you run into problems writing the code, ask about specific problems here. Don't ask SO to write your code for you. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note, you don't need a third-party library if it is actually a .csv... you can just use the standard library `csv` module

Comment: Sorry and ty for the notes.  I was definitely not trying to get anyone to write a code, was hoping someone knew of like a library or better algorithm to do so.  Ill update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel PowerQuery should do the trick:

1. Load .txt file as a table (list)
2. Load sheet with the data columns as another table
3. Merge (e.g. Left join) first table with second table
4. Optional: adjust/select the columns to be included or excluded in the resulting table

In Python with Pandas’ data frames the same can be accomplished (joining 2 data frames)

P.S. Pandas supports loading CSV files and txt files (as a variant of CSV) into a data frame

Comment: ty, appreciate it, definitely much easier than my original way